# Нажатие на кнопку и изменение виджета

Tags: flutter

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class AddButton extends StatefulWidget {
  AddButton({required this.product, required this.count, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
    
      final Product product;
      int count;
    
      @override
      _AddButton createState() => _AddButton(product: product,count: count);
    
    }
    
    
    class _AddButton extends State<AddButton>{
      _AddButton({required this.product, required this.count});
    
      final Product product;
      int count;
      bool showWdiget = false;
    
      void _incrementCounterPlus(){
        setState((){
          count++;
          if(count<=0) {
            showWdiget = true;
          }
        });
      }
      void _incrementCounterMinus(){
        setState((){
          count--;
          if(count == 0){
            showWdiget = false;
          }
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: showWdiget ? DefaultBtn(product: product) : CounterBtn(product: this.product,count: this.count),
        );
      }
    }
    
    
    
    class DefaultBtn extends _AddButton{
      DefaultBtn({required this.product, Key? key})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            CupertinoButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              onPressed: () {
                final model = Provider.of<AppStateModel>(context, listen: false);
                model.addProductToCart(product.id);
                _incrementCounterPlus();
                // _AddButton(product: product,count:-1);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Add',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
    
    
    class CounterBtn extends _AddButton {
      CounterBtn({required this.product, required this.count, Key? key})
          : super(key: key);
    
      final Product product;
      int count;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            CupertinoButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              onPressed: () {
                final model = Provider.of<AppStateModel>(context, listen: false);
                model.removeItemFromCart(product.id);
                _incrementCounterMinus();
                // _AddButton(product: product,count:-1);
              },
              child: const Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.minus_square,
                semanticLabel: 'Minus',
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              this.count.toString(),
            ),
            CupertinoButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              onPressed: () {
                final model = Provider.of<AppStateModel>(context, listen: false);
                model.addProductToCart(product.id);
                _incrementCounterPlus();
              },
              child: const Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.plus_circled,
                semanticLabel: 'Add',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в этом:

```
class DefaultBtn extends _AddButton{
class CounterBtn extends _AddButton {
```

Вы наследуетесь от `_AddButton`, он в свою очередь наследуется от `State<AddButton>`, но `State` это не `Widget`.

---

Если вам нужен общий интерфейс с логикой, то можно это сделать как-то так:

```
mixin ProductMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  late final Product _product;
  Product get product => _product;

  late int _count;
  int get count => _count;

  bool _showWdiget = false;
  bool get _showWdiget => showWdiget ;

  void init(Product p, int c) {
    _product = p;
    _count = c;
  }

  void incrementCounterPlus(){
    setState((){
      _count++;
      if(count<=0) {
        _showWdiget = true;
      }
    });
  }
  void incrementCounterMinus(){
    setState((){
      _count--;
      if(count == 0){
        _showWdiget = false;
      }
    });
  }
}

class DefaultBtn extends StatefulWidget {
  DefaultBtn({required this.product, required this.count, Key? key})
  : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  int count;

  @override
  State createState() => _DefaultBtnState();
}

class _DefaultBtnState extends State<DefaultBtn> with ProductMixin {
  @override
  initState() {
    init(widget.product, widget.count);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        CupertinoButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          onPressed: () {
            final model = Provider.of<AppStateModel>(context, listen: false);
            model.addProductToCart(widget.product.id);
            incrementCounterPlus();
          },
          child: const Text(
            'Add',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CounterBtn extends StatefulWidget {
  CounterBtn({required this.product, required this.count, Key? key})
  : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  int count;

  @override
  State createState() => _CounterBtnState();
}

class _CounterBtnState extends State<CounterBtn> with ProductMixin {
  @override
  initState() {
    init(widget.product, widget.count);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        CupertinoButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          onPressed: () {
            final model = Provider.of<AppStateModel>(context, listen: false);
            model.removeItemFromCart(widget.product.id);
            incrementCounterMinus();
          },
          child: const Icon(
            CupertinoIcons.minus_square,
            semanticLabel: 'Minus',
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          count.toString(),
        ),
        CupertinoButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          onPressed: () {
            final model = Provider.of<AppStateModel>(context, listen: false);
            model.addProductToCart(widget.product.id);
            incrementCounterPlus();
          },
          child: const Icon(
            CupertinoIcons.plus_circled,
            semanticLabel: 'Add',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

---

В `State` не нужно делать конструктор для передачи параметров, так как к ним можно обратится через геттер `widget`. Пример также есть в коде.

*P.S. писал все без редактора возможны ошибки.*

Comment: Вопрос, а как происходит смена виджета тогда ?

Comment: setState. Миксин на основе стейта, имеет все возможности стейта.

Comment: Можно было проще сделать через виджет Visibility

Comment: Я ответ дал на основе вашего кода. Можно по разному делать....